# camel unpacking tar.gzip files

Tags: apache-camel, gzip, tar

After downloading several files with camel over FTP I should process them but they are in tar.gzip formats. Camel supports gzip and as I can see also tar endpoint from 2.16.0 onwards (http://camel.apache.org/camel-2160-release.html).

**The code I have for extracting the gzip:**

```
from("file:modelFiles?readLock=changed&recursive=true&consumer.delay=1000")
        .unmarshal(new ZipFileDataFormat())
               .choice()
                    .when(body().isNotNull())
                        .log("Uziping file ${file:name}.")
                        .to("file:modelFiles_unzipped")
                    .endChoice()
        .end();
```

All the files run through the rule but they are created as .tar.gz again but the worse is that the content also becomes corrupt, so they cannot even be opened afterwards as gzip archives.

**Questions:**

1. How should I unpack the gzip archives?
2. How could I do the same for
       the tar files?

**Update 1:**

Thanks for the post Jeremie. I changed the code like this as proposed:

```
                from("file:modelFilesSBML2?readLock=changed&recursive=true&consumer.delay=1000")
                    .unmarshal().gzip()
                    .split(new TarSplitter())
                    .to("file:modelFilesSBML_unzipped");
```

Then I receive the following exception (just for info the tar.gzip files are not of zero length): **FailedException: Cannot write null body to file: modelFilesSBML_unzipped\2006-01-31\BioModels_Database-r4-sbml_files.tar.gz** :

```
2016-03-22 14:11:47,950 [ERROR|org.apache.camel.processor.DefaultErrorHandler|MarkerIgnoringBase] Failed delivery for (MessageId: ID-JOY-49807-1458652278822-0-592 on ExchangeId: ID-JOY-49807-1458652278822-0-591). Exhausted after delivery attempt: 1 caught: org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileOperationFailedException: Cannot write null body to file: modelFilesSBML_unzipped\2006-01-31\BioModels_Database-r4-sbml_files.tar.gz
```

**Solution:**

After trying many ways, I am using it finally as follows (with **Camel 2.17.0** it did not work with 2.16.0 or 2.16.1):

```
from("file:modelFilesSBML?noop=true&recursive=true&consumer.delay=1000" )
    .unmarshal().gzip()
    .split(new TarSplitter())
    .to("log:tar.gzip?level=INFO&showHeaders=true")
           .choice()
                .when(body().isNotNull())
                    .log("### Extracting file: ${file:name}.")
                    .to("file:modelFilesSBML_unzipped?fileName=${in.header.CamelFileRelativePath}_${file:name}")    
            .endChoice()                                
    .end();
```

**With Camel 2.17.0 you can also skip the body().isNotNull() check.**

Jeremie's proposal help much, so I will accept his answer as a solution. Nevertheless, the exception would still come, if I did not check the message body for null. The **fileName=${in.header.CamelFileRelativePath}_${file:name}** keeps also the original file structure where the file name is prefixed with the file.tar.gz but I have not found any other way to preserve the directory structure as the file endpoint does not accept expressions for the directory in ("file:directory?options...").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `camel-tarfile` component.

If your tar.gz contain multiple files, you should ungzip, then untar and split the exchange for each file. The `TarSplitter` is an expression which split a tar into an iterator for each file contained in the tar.

```
from("file:target/from")
    .unmarshal().gzip()
    .split(new TarSplitter())
    .to("file:target/to");
```

Comment: Thanks Jeremie, I tried it but then an exception complains about the null body. This is similar to the original exception for which I added a null body check in the original code but then everything is omitted.

Comment: I don't know. I have tested the code in my answer with severals tar.gz on my machine, it was working without null check.

Comment: Jeremie, what do you think about the solution? I mean the part for keeping the original directory structures. Thank again for your comment.